# open a foreign URL & then continue with my own webpages

Tags: php, javascript, url, curl

http://bulksms.poweredsms.com/send.php?usr=rajdeeps&pwd=pass123&ph=xxxxxxxxxxx&sndr=textid&text=hi

I need to open this url, but there is no way I can redirect back to my own website from this link, is there any way to execute this link & den carry on with other webpages I want...??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CURL for this.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you mean with "executing" a url, if you just want to call it, you can use AJAX, open an popup or just do something like this (very ugly method):

```
<img src="url....." style="display: none;">
```

Edit:

One example of using AJAX is here:

[Get result from php file without usig jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069539/get-result-from-php-file-without-usig-jquery/9069599#9069599)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this way using cURL

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init("http://bulksms.poweredsms.com/send.php?usr=rajdeeps&pwd=pass123&ph=xxxxxxxxxxx&sndr=textid&text=hi");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ch);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: do i need to include any library for this?

Comment: No library is needed for this. cURL is enabled on PHP by default.

Comment: Click the WAMP icon on your taskbar near datetime, Select PHP -> PHP Extensions -> Click php_curl to enable it. Click the WAMP icon again and choose "Restart all services".