# Cross-domain XMLHttpRequest from an essentially domainless mobile app?

Tags: javascript, cordova, network-programming, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I'm making a mobile app using the PhoneGap framework, which is to say that the entire app is written in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Part of the app requires me to fetch some information from a remote database.

I've spent the last hour reading up on how to make an XMLHttpRequest() to a remote domain, and I can't figure it out for the life of me.

As a bonus, since the goal of the request is to retrieve some database content, I need to send 3 parameters to the server for querying with.

I keep seeing things about the same-origin policy, but I can't find anything clearly saying whether it would apply to a phonegap app which has no actual host. I've also seen about 6 fairly overcomplicated workarounds. Before I go to the trouble of implementing one of those, I'd like to confirm that there isn't nowadays some simple way of doing this. Can anyone show an example, if so?

Comment: Maybe this will work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069539/get-result-from-php-file-without-usig-jquery/9069599#9069599

Comment: The "same origin policy" is irrelevant for an application written with something like PhoneGap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same origin policy does not apply when you are running your XHR from the file:// protocol of the mobile device. Here is a small example I used to show how to make a XHR request to twitter.

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.ca/2011/12/on-third-day-of-phonegapping-getting.html