# Open an external URL and continue with my own webpages

Tags: php, javascript, url

The following is an example of a URL I use to send SMS via an external site:

http://bulksms.poweredsms.com/send.php?usr=rajdeeps&pwd=pass123&ph=xxxxxxxxxxx&sndr=textid&text=hi

But if I redirect the user to this URL, they will not be redirected back to my website.
However I have code to execute/pages to display sending the message.

How can I load the URL to send the message without loosing the control over what is displayed to the user?

Comment: If you want to do it with html/javascript you can use AJAX http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069539/get-result-from-php-file-without-usig-jquery/9069599#9069599 . But you shouldn't do this. You should use curl http://php.net/manual/de/book.curl.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to do that on the server side, for example with [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

```
    // create curl resource 
    $ch = curl_init(); 

    // set url 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://bulksms.poweredsms.com/send.php?usr=rajdeeps&pwd=pass123&ph=xxxxxxxxxxx&sndr=textid&text=hi"); 

    //return the transfer as a string 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

    // $output contains the output string 
    $output = curl_exec($ch); 

    // close curl resource to free up system resources 
    curl_close($ch);

    // $output now contains the response from poweredsms.com
```

Comment: error : undefined function curl_init(),
wat should I do(include lib?)